# can this be made to work? (multiple ul in columns)

Tags: php, mysql, css, internet-explorer

Can get something working with css3 for safari and firefox but ie won't have a piece of it. I'm outputting a list of shopping categorys and sub categorys with a seperate  for each list.

This is what I've got (not working so far).. Any help would be most welcomed.

```
<div style="float:left; width: 232px;">
<?
$rowcount = 1;                          
$strSql = "SELECT * FROM Category ORDER BY CategoryName ASC";
$r = $db->select($strSql);
while ($row=$db->get_row($r, 'MYSQL_ASSOC')) {  
    $CategoryID = $row['CategoryID'];
    $CategoryName = $row['CategoryName'];
    ?>
     <div style="width: 232px; background-color:#f2f2f2; padding: 5px; margin-top: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden; padding-left: 5px;">
          <h1><a href="/<?=$colour?>/<?=$CategoryURL?>/" ><?=$CategoryName?></a></h1>
            <ul>
                  <?                        
                  $strSql2 = "SELECT 
                  SubCategory.SubCategoryID,
                  SubCategory.SubCategoryName,
                  SubCategory.SubCategoryURL,
                  SubCategory.CategoryID
                FROM
                  SubCategory
                WHERE
                  CategoryID = $CategoryID
                ORDER BY
                  SubCategoryName";
                  // echo "<pre>$strSql</pre>";
                  $r2 = $db->select($strSql2);
                  while ($row2=$db->get_row($r2, 'MYSQL_ASSOC')) {
                      $SubCategoryID = $row2['SubCategoryID'];
                      $SubCategoryName = $row2['SubCategoryName'];
                      $SubCategoryURL = $row2['SubCategoryURL'];
                  ?>    
                  <li><a href="/<?=$colour?>/<?=$CategoryURL?>/<?=$SubCategoryURL?>/"><?=$SubCategoryName?> (<?=$rowcount?>)</a></li>
                  <?
                  $rowcount++;
                  if ($rowcount == 35) { echo"</ul></div><div style=\"float:left; width: 232px;\"><ul>"; $rowcount = 0;} 
                  } // end get SubCategory
                  ?>
               <? if ($rowcount == 0) { echo""; } else {echo"</ul>";} ?>
               </div>       
         <? } // end get category list
?>     
        </ul> <!-- END CATEGORY UL -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is a CSS layout question, all the PHP/MySQL is irrelevant. Can you please post the output HTML markup this produces instead of the PHP?

Comment: what is the exact problem? Do you want them to line up in a row but they are breaking at each line? Also it looks like you'd have some weird closures. Is the outputted HTML what you expect to see? The reason I ask is taht if the rowcount == 35 you close the sub category ul and open another div and ul. So it looks like if you reach 35 rows you close it off and end the subcategory w/ an empty div and empty ul.

Comment: I could well have it the wrong way around to get the end result. The end result is what you would expect to see if you have dumped lots of ul into a four column layout in word. If there is an open list I want it to wrap round and continue in the next column. Ideally I'd like to work out if the complete list will fit in the remaining height of the column and if not for the full list to start a new column without breaking but I have no clue how to even start working that through.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use a table-based layout, which in this case I don't think would be that bad. Tables are for tabular data and catalog categories would fit well. **Edit:** But you'd still have to figure out your PHP logic to get this working. Derp on my part.

Alternatively, there is the [Columnizer jQuery plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) to do the trick automagically but I'm not fond of having to rely on a javascript-driven solution for layout elements. Although you could trigger it for only the browsers that don't support your CSS3 method via Modernizr. Still not a huge fan of this.

Can you post the CSS3 you used that is working in other browsers? Perhaps there is an available workaround that would do the trick. I'm still a bit fuzzy on the details for your end result. I'm focusing on the CSS aspect of your issue and less on the PHP. Finding a working CSS-driven solution is obviously far easier than trying to figure out the logic to divide your categories into columns accordingly.

Comment: Initially used -moz-column-count: 4; on a div surrounding these lists without the rowcount == 35 part, it produced the list nicely formated into 4 columns (except in ie). I'm looking to replicate something like gumtree's layout. With the php I'm trying (and failing because I'm very new to it) to come up with something that will count down x number of rows (35 in this instance) and if there is and open ul close it. close the container div, open a new div floated alongside it and start off again. I know I'm missing something here.. Here is what I have //www.coloursupermarket.co.uk/xindex.php

Comment: http://www.coloursupermarket.co.uk/yindex.php is what the css produces and I was happy until I checked ie out..